# How to read a json data into a dataframe using pandas

Tags: python, json, pandas

I have json data which is in the structure below:

```
{"Text1": 4, "Text2": 1, "TextN": 123}
```

I want to read the json file and make a dataframe such as

[image]

Each key value pairs will be a row in the dataframe and I need to need headers "Sentence" and "Label". I tried with using **lines = True** but it returns all the key-value pairs in one row.

```
data_df = pd.read_json(PATH_TO_DATA, lines = True)
```

What is the correct way to load such json data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use:

```
with open('json_example.json') as json_data:
    data = json.load(json_data)

df=pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data,orient='index').reset_index().rename(columns={'index':'Sentence',0:'Label'})
```

Answer (score 0):

### Easy way that I remember

```py
import pandas as pd
import json

with open("./data.json", "r") as f:
    data = json.load(f)

df = pd.DataFrame({"Sentence": data.keys(), "Label": data.values()})
```

### With read_json

To read straight from the file using `read_json`, you can use something like:

```py
pd.read_json("./data.json", lines=True)\
    .T\
    .reset_index()\
    .rename(columns={"index": "Sentence", 0: "Labels"})
```

#### Explanation

A little dirty but as you probably noticed, `lines=True` isn't completely sufficient so the above *transposes* the result so that you have

| (index) | 0 |
| --- | --- |
| Text1 | 4 |
| Text2 | 1 |
| TextN | 123 |

So then resetting the index moves the index over to be a column named "index" and then renaming the columns.